# Error when using r and l value constructors in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor, overloading

I have a class template like this:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
     MyClass(const T & val);  // First
     MyClass(T&& val);        // Second
};
```

Basically I want MyClass to be constructible from a `T` whether it's an rvalue or an lvalue. Now when I have something like

```
const A& foo = ...;
MyClass<const A&> x(foo);
```

I get redefinition error for `MyClass(const A & val)`.

I presume this is because T&& is a universal reference and due to reference collapsing rules, the second constructor also gets converted to having the same signature as the first.

Firstly is my understanding of the error scenario correct? secondly how can I get around this problem(I want to able the use the optimizations that move semantics provide when constructing MyClass)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I presume this is because T&& is a universal reference ...

Incorrect. `T&&` is not a universal (forwarding) reference in this case. `T&&` is exactly an rvalue reference to `T`. Universal/forwarding references must be deduced.

> ... and due to reference collapsing rules, the second constructor also gets converted to having the same signature as the first.

*This* is correct. Our two constructors take:

```
T const& ==> A const& const& ==> A const&
T&&      ==> A const& &&     ==> A const&
```

hence the redefinition error.

Depending on what it is you want to do, a simple solution might be to just [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) `T`:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
    using DecT = typename std::decay<T>::type;

public:
    MyClass(const DecT& );
    MyClass(DecT&& );
};
```

For your example, that will still create a class with two constructors: one taking `const A&` and the other taking `A&&`.

Comment: ok, now how can I get around the problem? without sacrificing on the constructor that takes an r-value?

Comment: @Arun Wrote one approach. Another would be to just... not allow `MyClass` to take reference types with a static assert and enforce that somewhere else.

Comment: `A const& const&` is `A const &`. Ditto for `A const& &&`.

Comment: Isn't the right answer here to just use `T` with no const/reference qualifiers as the template parameter?
`MyClass<A> f(x);` will work with lvalue and rvalue x's.